# Hide the tablecells in UITableView in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

In my application I would like to hide the table cells in uitableview , and I don't want to hide the header of the tableview in iPhone. On that table view header I would like to add a button, so if anyone know this how to hide the cells in a tableview without hiding the header in tableview in iphone.

Comment: what about, in `numberOfRowsInSection`, if section==x { return 0; }

Comment: do you want to create a accordion ????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all cells in a section, just set the number of rows in that section to 0!

Answer (score 0):

Use table Dalegate method put height of that row 0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```